# C#: DataGridView with DataGridViewColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I got an Application with a DataGridView. When I'm adding a new DataGridViewColumn to it, the whole Window is white and no DataGridView appears. I searched for this problem but found nothing.

`columns` is an Array of Strings

```
foreach (String strings in columns) {
            DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column.Name = strings;
            column.HeaderText = strings;
            grid.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

But when I'm adding a new Column without instancing a new DataGridViewColumn, the DataGridView appears in the Window:

```
foreach (String strings in columns) {
            grid.Columns.Add(strings, strings);
}
```

The problem is that I have to have these DataGridViewColumns in my App. What can I do?

Comment: Isn't there a build-in function to do this in Visual Studio?

Comment: @thijmen321 for what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be getting an error, but in any case, you have to specify the column type:

```
var column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
column.Name = strings;
column.HeaderText = strings;
grid.Columns.Add(column);
```